# How to I get a current date but with a fixed time in my SQL Where

Tags: sql, oracle, select

In my where I want to get is_my_day < current date with a fixed time (ie 0600 hrs).  What's the syntax?  This is the current format but I want to specify a fixed time for my automated report. I am using Oracle 10.

```
WHERE
TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE - 8/24,'hh24'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

Option  one you compare DATE-values direct

```
WHERE
   MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND < 
                        trunc(SYSDATE, 'DD') + INTERVAL '06:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
```

`SYSDATE` -  current date , current time

`TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD')` -  current date,  00:00 hrs

`'TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') + INTERVAL '06:00' HOUR TO MINUTE'`  - current date, 06:00 hrs

---

Option two: you convert date values to strings und compare strings

```
WHERE
 TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') < 
                                          to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd') || '0600'
```

`to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd')` -- returns  `20130726`

Comment: Yep, those options look cleaner than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit ugly IMO but it's the only thing I can think of for now.

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
    < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)) + 6/24, 'hh24'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```